# WSO2 Developer Studio 3.2.0 does not include outSequence in proxy service definition

Tags: wso2

I installed WSO2 Developer Studio 3.2.0 on Eclipse Kepler. I have created an ESB Config Project and defined a proxy service in this project. In this proxy definition there are inSequence, outSequence and faultSequence parts each including set of mediators.

I have created a Carbon Application project and added the artifact as a dependency. After deployment,  in final *.car file, I see that the proxy service definition is changed in a way that outSequence does not include any mediators. At deployment stage, outSequence content is emptied. What could be the problem?

Comment: Consider that Developer Studio 3.2.0 is not ready to work with ESB 4.8.0, but with earlier versions. An update is coming.

Comment: The problem is not related to the version of the ESB. When I look inside the archive (*.car file), I see that no mediator exists under outSequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, WSO2 Dev Studio is not compatible with Eclipse Kepler. Recommended Eclipse version is Eclipse Juno SR2.

You will experience this problem if you have entered incorrect properties or parameters for a mediator in your OutSequence of the Proxy service. This issue is now fixed in upcoming WSO2 Dev Studio 3.5 version where it will provide you an error message when there is such incorrect or incompatible property/parameter is used.

Therefore please use latest Developer Studio 3.5 version and retry the example.

Hope this helps!!

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana